# How to calculate the derivative/gradient of this scalar product?

Tags: inner-products, neural-networks

in my exam prep I have the following:

[image]

I need to calculate the gradient of this function f.
So I start using the chain rule but how do I get the derivative of <x,wi>?

Why does the x of the derivative disappear?
I tried to use: <a,b> = a'b+b'a.

But wouldn't this give me x+w?
Is this formular wrong to use in this context?

The solution only states this but not how to get there:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to use the definition of partial derivatives.

Comment: But isn't it what I tried?<x,wi> = x'wi + wi`x? Derivative of x times w plus derivative of w times x? But the solution only has w at the end not x'wi + wi'x

Comment: I guess $w_i$ is the $i$-th basis element. Then let $g(x) = \langle x, w_i\rangle$. By definition, $\partial_i g(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}$.

Comment: It should be that $\partial_i g(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+hw_i)-g(x)}{h}$.

Comment: Is $\{ w_i \}_{i = 1}^m$ an orthonormal basis?